# Java implementations of the lasso

Tags: regression, lasso, java

Are there any open-source Java implementations of lasso or least angles regression?

Pure Java code would be best, but clean implementations in other languages would also be of interest. I am already aware of the existence of a variety of R packages than can do lasso/LAR fits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About clean implementation in Python, there is the [scikit.learn](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/) toolkit. The [L1/L2 regularization scheme](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/modules/glm.html) (incl. *elasticnet*) works great with GLM (LARS and coordinate descent algorithms available). Don't know about Java implementation.

Answer (score 4):

[lasso4j](http://code.google.com/p/lasso4j/) is an open source Java implementation of Lasso for linear regression.

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across [mlpy](https://mlpy.fbk.eu/), which also has an implementation of the lasso (in Python.)

Comment: (+1) Yes, I'm aware of that project too. But I know that those that are currently developing the `scikit.learn` are serious guys working in neuroimaging, and that the project will evolve and include ever growing features.

Comment: @chi I've decided to go with `scikit.learn` as my reference implementation (and have accepted your answer.) It looks like high-quality code.